# How to install Cefsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to use Cefsharp. I made like these steps->

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <runtime> <-this one
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> <-this one
            <probing privatePath="x86"/> <-this one
        </assemblyBinding> <-this one
    </runtime> <-this one
</configuration>
```

I have x64 windows. I changed platform for project x86(I don't know is it right or not ..)
and I added this one to
Project.csproj

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{BAB75200-56BD-4B29-8A12-2D7CC07C497D}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Mps3</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Mps3</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <CefSharpAnyCpuSupport>True</CefSharpAnyCpuSupport> <-this one
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
...
```

Using Cfsherp is appeared. BUT when I'm trying to take element ChromoniumWebBrowser, it's saying failed to load element Chromewebbrowser . What I'm doing wrong. I'm using C# netframework Windows Forms

Comment: You've added the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/) right?

Comment: Please make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1714 You will need to set prefer 32bit.

Comment: I Nuget package for CefSharp ? Of course yes . I'm seeing using Cefsharp;

Comment: And what can I do if don't have 32bit ?

Comment: Okay, I DON'T know what have I done but now this error has gone...